# What effect do particles in superposition have?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, superposition

Say, with the double slit experiment, in the space between the slits and the wall, what effect does the particle have on those in the air? Is the momentum so spread out to not be measurable with the effect?

Comment: It is assumed that the space between the wall and the slit is vacant. If you put some gas, the electron might scatter through the gas.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi there's no such thing as a perfect vacuum.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi even if there were a perfect vacuum a particle would still have an effect on the walls.

Comment: Yes, there will be but it depends on what you are using as particles and the material of the wall. You should be more specific.

Comment: @Young Kindaichi what particles have no effect on their surroundings?